# DataTables won't work in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, datatables, thymeleaf

I have a table, where on row click a modal window is opened. Thanks to this:

```
th:onclick="'javascript:openPoolModal(\''+ ${networkHashrate.id} + '\');'"
```

`openPoolModal.js` looks like:

```
function openPoolModal(id){

$.ajax({
    url: "/" + id,
    success: function(data){
    $("#PoolModalHolder").html(data);
    $("#personalModal").modal();
    $("#personalModal").modal('show');
}
});
}
```

`PoolModalHolder` is just an empty div on my `main.html` file, where the first table is rendered. `personalModal` is a fragment of code that opens on a modal dialog.

A modal dialog is then filled with `personalModal`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="personalModal" role="dialog" th:fragment="modalContents">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" th:text="'Network Id: ' + ${poolHashrates[0].networkHashrate.id}">Network Id</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table width="100%" class="table table-hover " id="poolTable">

                    <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Pool name</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Date from</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Hashrate</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="poolHashrate : ${poolHashrates}">
                        <td class="text-center" th:text="${poolHashrate.poolDef.name}"> Sample data</td>
                        <td class="text-center" th:text="${poolHashrate.poolDef.date_from}">Maven Street 10, Glasgow</td>
                        <td class="text-center" th:text="${poolHashrate.hashrate}">999-999-999</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't get the `DataTables` to work on the table inside `personalModal` window.

The standard `DataTables` initialization doesn't work and that is:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#poolTable').DataTable();
} );
```

I have also tried this, but with same result:

```
$( "#personalModal" ).focus(function() {
$('#poolTable').DataTable();
});
```

I have header links added and those are: jQuery, Bootstrap, DataTables.js.

I have also tried with `table-responsive` example, but again, doesn't work. Data is generated correctly through Spring controller method. I just need to apply sorting & pagination to the table.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, are you getting console errors? Is the jQuery selector for the table accessible from the console, or any other elements on the modal page?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#personalModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#poolTable').DataTable();
})`?